# Cómo guardar la "ImageUrl" en cada usuario?

Tags: android, android-studio, map, hashmap

**A. Cedano, basicamente quisiera que cada usuario tenga su propia imageurl ya que la usarán como foto de perfil
Espero que me puedas ayudar, igual muchas gracias!**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera que la imageurl esté dentro de cada usuario

> este es el codigo actual

**//Esta parte es para guardar la imagen en el Storage**

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == Gallery_Intent){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri ImageData = data.getData();

            final StorageReference Imagename = mstorage.child("image" + ImageData.getLastPathSegment());
```

**//Desde aquí empieza la parte que debería mandarme la ImageUrl a la Database**

```
Imagename.putFile(ImageData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Imagename.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                DatabaseReference imagestore = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User/Image");
                                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                                hashMap.put("imageurl", String.valueOf(uri));

                                imagestore.setValue(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Toast.makeText(Pantallaprincipal.this,"Exito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: En ese caso tienes que modificar el código en dos partes: 1) Creas la referencia así: **`DatabaseReference imagestore = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");`**  2) No uses `HashMap`, simplemente añade la url de la imagen dentro de un hijo de `User` que se llamaría `imageurl`, algo así: **`imagestore.child("imageurl").push().setValue(String.valueOf(uri));`** Ahí te va a agregar el valor al mismo nivel de `nombre, email ... ` etc.

Comment: no funciono, pero gracias de todos modos!

Comment: Es probable que debas usar la referencia que se crea en ese momento de ese usuario. No aparece en tu código cómo se crea el usuario. En esa referencia debes poner un `child("imageurl").push().setValue(String.valueOf(uri))` y se crearía correctamente. ¿Cómo asignas los otros valores, `DNI, celular...`etc? ¿Por qué no asignas ahí mismo el valor de `imageurl`?

Comment: porque la tengo en otro activity, estoy programando una app con ayuda de Youtube, buscaré tutoriales de cómo usar referencias, gracias!

Comment: El problema es que, ¿ves el código larguísimo que hay al principio del nodo que empieza por `E2St...`? Significa que se creó un objeto de forma automática y Firebase le asignó ese identificador. Entonces, para meter otro hijo dentro de ese objeto tienes que identificarlo de alguna manera. Quizá el método que estés usando para crear el usuario no sea el mejor ¿? Todo depende del contexto de tu app. Podrías identificarlo tú mismo por otro valor único, como el `DNI`, y también podrías poner `imageurl` al mismo tiempo que pones los otros datos. Es extraño que lo quieras hacer en dos tiempos.

Comment: Tienes razón, mejor  lo hago en la activity de crear usuario (Donde esta ubicado el map) y luego en otra solo pongo un boton para que cambie de foto, gracias por la paciencia, saludos.

Comment: Hey, ya encontré la manera de que salga dentro de cada usuario sin necesidad de hacerlo en la parte de crear usuario                ´DatabaseReference imagestore = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
                                imagestore.child(nAuth.getUid()).push().setValue(String.valueOf(uri));'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo he utilizado firebase también, y lo que hago es crear un objeto, en tu caso podría ser un objeto usuario por ejemplo, y le seteas los datos que necesites, en tu caso DNI, CELULAR, DIRECCION, EMAIL, NOMBRE, PASSWORD y aquí tienes que añadir el URI.

Firebase te permite subir objetos enteros y les da la misma estructura. Asi luego lo podrás recuperar todo junto.

EJ:

```
 Incidencia i = new Incidencia();
 i.setImgUri(faceIncidencia);
 i.setLinea(lineaIncidencia);
 i.setMensaje(textoIncidencia);
 i.setTime(fecha);
 i.setNombre(uLoged.getNombre());

 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("xxxxxxxxxx");
 DatabaseReference db = database.getReference("incidencias");
 db().setValue(i);
```

Espero te pueda ayudar, un saludo.

Comment: muchas gracias, intentaré aplicarlo, saludos